# Nginx : simple try_files with 301 return doesn't redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect

I would like to make Nginx redirect to an external URL when a resource is not found locally. This is my config :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
       try_files $uri @redirect;
       if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
    }

    location @redirect {
        return 301 https://myfallbacksite.net$request_uri;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

When I try to access a non-existing resource, I just get a 404 and the request is not redirected to the fallback website.

I think that it worked before so there may be a stupid typo somewhere. The Nginx error log says:

```
2018/10/28 10:22:35 [error] 9#9: *11 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/picture.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /picture.png HTTP/1.1", host: "myvhost", referrer: "https://www.originwebsite.com"
```

... which is true (the resource doesn't exist) but I would like the request to be redirected instead of sending back a 404.

Comment: Hi, check if permissions of /usr/share/nginx/html changed ? If not, try clearing your browser cache and try again

Comment: @ben5556 Thanks for your suggestion. Since I get a 404 even when trying to fetch the resource from inside that machine (doing `curl http://localhost/picture.png` ) it can't be a browser cache issue. Also, if it were a permission issue I think that I would get a "Permission denied" error and not "No such file or directory" in the error log

Comment: I think maybe this is a classic ["if is evil"](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) situation.

Comment: Yes, on doing a quick test removing the `if` block gives expected results. Putting back the `if` block results in 404.

Comment: @ben5556 and @Richard Smith thanks a lot! Indeed, if I leave the `add_header` lines but without the `if` wrapping it works! If one of you wants to write an answer above I will accept it :-)

Comment: I think Richard Smith should post an answer as his suggestion was spot on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ben5556 and @Richard Smith hinted, the `if` statement is in cause here. The Nginx documentation actually [has a page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) recommending not to use it if possible. When I removed the `if` wrapping around the `add_header` instructions, everything worked again.